# Android location service gets killed

Tags: android, android-location

I have a problem with the locationlistener in android.
For some reason it stops and gets killed.

Let's begin from the start.
I have an Activity which will start the GPS.

```
private void CheckEnableGPS() {
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //      String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        startGPS();
    } else {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }

}

private void startGPS()
{
    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getApp().startGPSMonitor();
}
```

First i binded the GPSService to my app.

```
bindService(new Intent(this, GpsService.class), mGpsServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Now I just start a service, instead of binding it

```
startService(new Intent(this, GpsService.class));
```

The GPSService class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(MobileConnectorApplication.APPLICATION_TAG, "Started GPS Service");
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, THIRTY_SECONDS, 0, this);
    } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, THIRTY_SECONDS, 0, this);
    }
}

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    MobileConnectorApplication app = ((MobileConnectorApplication) getApplication());
    Location oldLocation = app.getLastGpsLocation();

    if (isBetterLocation(location, oldLocation)) {
        updateLocation.latitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
        updateLocation.longitude = (float) location.getLongitude();
        updateLocation.user = app.getLoggedInUser();

        try {
            updateLocation.execute();
            app.setLastGpsLocation(location);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(MobileConnectorApplication.APPLICATION_TAG, "GPSSERVICE - Sending action failed", e);
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            Log.d(MobileConnectorApplication.APPLICATION_TAG, "GPSSERVICE - Httpexception", e);
        }
        notifyBroadCastListeners(location);
    }
}
```

I need this to run 24/7, to update every 30 seconds. Don't talk about battery consumption or so, as this is no issue to me. I tried declaring a wakelock that gets created in the oncreate event of this service.
It did not seems to help.
I did read that locationlistener should have it's own wakelock? Is this true?
Do I need to declare a wakelock somewhere else?

Is there someone that can help me to achieve this?

For more information, I got some logs where the locationprovider gets killed.
Also, does my application gets recycled? (I needed to log back in afterwards)

```
13:24:24.835: D/ConnectivityService(1475): ConnectivityService FeatureUser expire(0, enableSUPL, android.os.Binder@407cf348)
13:24:24.835: D/ConnectivityService(1475): stopUsingNetworkFeature for net 0: enableSUPL  
13:24:24.835: D/ConnectivityService(1475): ignoring - this process has no outstanding requests
13:25:47.453: D/TrackDroid(2341): Executing be.resultants.trackdroid.services.actions.UpdateLocationAction@40591dc0
13:25:54.195: D/SntpClient(1475): request time failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Try again
13:25:54.195: D/GpsLocationProvider(1475): requestTime failed  
13:27:55.523: D/CallManager(1539):  handleMessage (EVENT_SERVICE_STATE_CHANGED)
13:27:55.796: D/StatusChecker(5014): onReceive : android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
13:27:55.804: D/StatusChecker(5014): Service state changed : 0
13:27:55.812: D/StatusChecker(5014): trySendSMS, in service : true , SMS send : false , SMSC : true
13:27:55.828: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1475): replacing old mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for hipri
13:27:55.851: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1475): supl Received state= CONNECTED, old= CONNECTED, reason= (unspecified), apnTypeList= default,supl
13:27:55.921: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1475): default Received state= CONNECTED, old= CONNECTED, reason= (unspecified), apnTypeList= default,supl
13:27:55.937: W/GpsLocationProvider(1475): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
13:27:55.937: D/GpsLocationProvider(1475): stopNavigating
13:27:55.937: V/GpsLocationProvider(1475): reportStatus status: 2
13:27:55.937: D/GpsLocationProvider(1475): send an intent to notify that the GPS has been enabled or disabled
13:27:55.960: V/GpsLocationProvider(1475): reportStatus status: 2
13:27:55.984: D/ProgramMonitor(4740):  onReceive -no
13:27:56.015: V/GpsLocationProvider(1475): reportStatus status: 2
13:27:56.085: I/Launcher(1549): onResume() ended
13:27:56.132: I/Launcher(1549): onPause()
13:27:56.414: D/dalvikvm(1475): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1616K, 40% free 6385K/10503K, external 3094K/3852K, paused 12ms+27ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) life cycle. They may be closed when the system need more resources.

There are several solutions for that: You can use [startForgraound()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) to prevent the system from recycling it. Or you can listen to system events to start your service. Such as when user open the device, when the user put the device on charge or anything else.